# How to jump smoothly in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I add a CharacterController to Player.But when I test the jump function,I find that the Player will move upwards immediately.

```
    if (Player.isGrounded) 
    {
        if (jump) 
        {
            Move.y = JumpSpeed;
            jump = false;
            Player.Move (Move * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
    Move += Physics.gravity * Time.deltaTime * 4f;
    Player.Move (Move * Time.fixedDeltaTime);`
```

Comment: A wider code sample would be usefull. Is this snippet located in FixedUpdate() ? Is there a RigidBody attached to your player gameobject?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You are calling `Player.Move()` twice in one frame. This might be an issue.
2. You are **adding** gravity to `Move` vector, which means it will always go upward when you call this code.
3. naming a variable like `Move` is not a good convention. It creates confusion while reading because there is already a method of same name. change it to `moveDirection`.

Here is sample code:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 6.0F;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
    public float gravity = 20.0F;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    CharacterController controller;
    void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update() {
        if (controller.isGrounded) {
            moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
            moveDirection *= speed;
            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;

        }
        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks^.^,It helps a lot